# Windows keyboard shortcut to move mouse cursor between two screens

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with its main screen(A) and a connected one(B).

Sometimes the mouse is on one screen(B) and I want it on another screen(A), but i'm just looking at the one screen(A) where the mouse isn't. I could drag a lot and look for it seeing for it to appear on A, or if B is on I can turn my head to B to see the cursor location on it(B)..so  I can see when it'll get to A as I move it, But it'd be easier if I could just with a keyboard shortcut, get the mouse cursor in the middle of my laptop screen(A).

So a key to move the cursor from one screen to the other screen to  a place I'd know where it is like the center. Even a mouse movement that does it, so long as whatever the move or key is works wherever the mouse is, would be ok. Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Win7 shortcut to position mouse in center of primary screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/384099/is-there-a-win7-shortcut-to-position-mouse-in-center-of-primary-screen)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), with the "[CoordMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm)" and the "[MouseMove](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm)" commands.

CoordMode:

> Sets coordinate mode for various commands to be relative to either the active window or the screen.

MouseMove:

> Moves the mouse cursor.

Here's an example to move it to the center of the current screen:

```
!z::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseMove, (A_ScreenWidth // 2), (A_ScreenHeight // 2)
return
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: `MouseMove` didn't work for me. What does work is: `DllCall("SetCursorPos", int, x, int, y)
`

Answer (score 2):

This script works for me:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


#SingleInstance Force ; if the script is updated, replace the one and only instance

!m::

; 80 = CM_MONITORS - which basically means - monitor count
SysGet, count, 80
if count !=2 return ; only handle duo, uno - nothing to do

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen    ; this is a must as the mouse coordinate are now relative to the whole screen (both monitors)

SysGet, mon_1, Monitor, 1
SysGet, mon_2, Monitor, 2
MouseGetPos mouse_x,mouse_y

; toggle the mouse to the middle of the other screen

if (mouse_x <= mon_1Right)
{
  new_x := mon_2Left + (mon_2Right - mon_2Left) // 2
  new_y := mon_2Top + (mon_2Bottom - mon_2Top) // 2
}
else
{
  new_x := mon_1Left + (mon_1Right - mon_1Left) // 2
  new_y := mon_1Top + (mon_1Bottom - mon_1Top) // 2
}

MouseMove, %new_x%, %new_y%
Click
return

Esc::ExitApp  ; Exit script with Escape key
```

Comment: Does the accepted answer not work for you?   Is this one better?   If so, how?

Comment: @Scott he has included some comments in the script

Answer (score 1):

Wrote my own script in [v2](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/) since scripts in previous answers are in v1.

- Works with any number of monitors.
- Handles different DPI res on different monitors.
- Forward/back mouse buttons switch to next/previous monitor.
- Will move cursor to same (scaled) relative position on monitor switched to

```
#SingleInstance Force

MouseSwitchMonitor(switchNumber := 1) {
    DllCall("SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext", "ptr", -3, "ptr")  ; handles multiple monitors with different DPI settings 
    CoordMode("Mouse", "Screen")
    
    count := MonitorGetCount()

    if (count <= 1) {
        return
    }

    MouseGetPos(&mouseX, &mouseY)
    relativeMouseX := 0.5
    relativeMouseY := 0.5
    mouseMonitor := 0

    monitors := {}

    counter := 1
    Loop count {
        actual := MonitorGet(counter, &left, &top, &right, &bottom)
        monitors.%actual% := {left: left, top: top, right: right, bottom: bottom}
        if (left <= mouseX && mouseX < right && top <= mouseY && mouseY < bottom) {  ; from testing, seems mouse position can be left or top but not right or bottom
            mouseMonitor := actual
            relativeMouseX := (mouseX - left) / (right - left)
            relativeMouseY := (mouseY - top) / (bottom - top)
        }
        counter++
    }

    mouseMonitor := Mod(mouseMonitor - 1 + Mod(switchNumber, count) + count, count) + 1  ; modular arithmetic to cycle, and make sure 1 <= mouseMonitor <= count

    if (!HasProp(monitors, mouseMonitor)) {
        return
    }
    monitor := monitors.%mouseMonitor%
    
    MouseMove(monitor.left + Floor(relativeMouseX * (monitor.right - monitor.left)), monitor.top + Floor(relativeMouseY * (monitor.bottom - monitor.top)), 0)  ; since mouse position can be left or top, but not right or bottom
}

XButton1::MouseSwitchMonitor(-1)  ; backward mouse button, previous monitor
XButton2::MouseSwitchMonitor(1)  ; forward mouse button, next monitor
```