# Windows Powershell doesn't seem to accept target paths with spaces

Tags: windows, powershell

I was following this thread [Is there a Win7 shortcut to position mouse in center of primary screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/384099/is-there-a-win7-shortcut-to-position-mouse-in-center-of-primary-screen)

Following the suggestion of the guy with 12 upvotes, I created a shortcut with the target file being

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned "C:\Program Files\My Scripts\CenterCursor"`

It just wouldn't work, unless the target file doesn't have any spaces inside the double quote

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\CenterCursor"`

It's just a minor issue but is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This worked for me:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>   -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned C:\Program Files\My` Scripts\CenterCursor

Note that you will need a <kbd>`</kbd> after each word (before the space) and you don't need the outer <kbd>"</kbd>.

[Source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-run-a-powershell-script-with-space-in-the-path/)

Comment: I spent ages trying to find a solution until I came across your answer. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1378532/907659) for a more general case.

Answer (score 12):

In a more general case, you can use the following syntax to run any PowerShell script with space in the path:

```
&("C:\any path with spaces in it\")
```

In your case, that would be:

```
&("C:\Program Files\My Scripts\CenterCursor")
```

**Edit:** this only works if you are using windows powershell

[Source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/07/powertip-run-a-powershell-script-with-space-in-the-path/)

Comment: You don't need the parentheses.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but what if the path is holded by a variable. How does the code then look?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to cheat by using the short name.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned "C:\Progra~1\MyScri~1\CenterCursor"
```

I guessed your short names based on likelihood, but you can find the real ones using [methods from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4051088/492773) like `dir /x`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the single quotes instead of double quotes, it might help.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could be improved by explaining how adding double-quotes helps, and perhaps providing an example line of code.